# What do the arguments in a PIL Affine Transform mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, transformation

I was working on getting a few images to skew and I found this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177744/how-does-perspective-transformation-work-in-pil) which had some code for skewing an Image along the x-axis:

```py
width, height = self.get_size()  # This is defined elsewhere to get the height & width of the image
new_width = width + int(round(abs(scale) * width))
self.img_PIL = self.img_PIL.transform((new_width, height), Img.AFFINE,
                                      (1, scale, -(abs(scale) * width) if scale > 0 else 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

But I don't seem to understand what this means... what are the 4 tuple values `0, 0, 1, 0`? What is `(1, scale, -(abs(scale) * width)`. And lastly, how would I adapt this for skewing the image on the y-axis? I would prefer to understand the logic behind the tuples because I would be able to adapt this for the y-axis myself.

Comment: The tuple is the `data` parameter to be used with the transformation method. This answer provides a lot of detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141975/10987432

Comment: I see, thanks! it took a bit of work, but I think I'm almost properly skewing the image.